Can this minus operation be implemented via a quantum channel?
For an any given $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2=1-\rho_1$, the initial density matrix $\varrho_0$ is $\varrho_0=$Diag$[\rho_1,\rho_2,0]$.
(Assume $\rho_1>\rho_2$, or swap them)
Can we extract $\rho_2/2$ from the first two place to the third place and get the density matrix $\varrho=$Diag$[\rho_1-\rho_2/2,\rho_2/2,\rho_2]$ ?
(This map is no doubt a trace-preserve and positive map, but it seems not a linear map.)

Of course you can assume $\rho_1>\rho_2$ to ensure a positive output for your particular problem, but that does not change the fact that there cannot be a positive linear map $\Phi:\mathbb C^{3\times 3}\to\mathbb C^{3\times 3}$ which satisfies
$$
\Phi\big({\rm diag}(\rho_1,\rho_2,0)\big)={\rm diag}\Big(\frac{\rho_1-\rho_2}2,\frac{\rho_2}2,\rho_2\Big)\tag1
$$
for all $\rho_1>\rho_2$. The reason for this is that
\begin{align*}
\Phi\big({\rm diag}(0,1,0)\big)&=\Phi\big(-{\rm diag}(0,-1,0)\big)\\
{\scriptsize(\Phi\text{ linear})\to\ }&=-\Phi\big({\rm diag}(0,-1,0)\big)\\
{\scriptsize(\text{Eq.}(1)\text{ because }0>-1)\to\ }&=-{\rm diag}\Big(\frac{0-(-1)}2,\frac{-1}2,-1\Big)\\
&={\rm diag}\Big(-\frac12,\frac12,1\Big)\,,
\end{align*}
thus violating positivity of $\Phi$.
Alternatively, if you re-define your map for $\rho_1\leq\rho_2$ in such a way that $\Phi$ becomes positive, it would not be linear anymore -- as you already observed yourself.

Very thanks to your answers.

I find if I constrain the linearity of $\Phi$ into density matrix, it transforms positive semidefinite matrices to positive semidefinite matrices. Moreover, I wander that if we can realize this map in quantum channel?

That's incorrect: as I showed in my answer, linearity forces that the density matrix ${\rm diag}(0,1,0)$ is mapped to ${\rm diag}(-\frac12,\frac12,1)$ which is not a density matrix anymore.
